# How to choose correct distribution in R

Tags: r, distributions, gamlss

I want to plot a probability distribution. I know the mean and think that a normal distribution would be a poor description of my beliefs. I either assume that the values smaller (or larger) than my mean are more likely to occur than the ones larger (or smaller). I don't know anything else, except, that the values are somehow in the vicinity of my mean...

For example, my mean is 0.151 and I believe that larger values are more likely to occur than smaller ones. What distribution should I choose and how can I implement this in `R`?

**EDIT**

The mean represents a share and therefore is limited to [0,1]. The change I want to predict will be relatively small and start from the mean, resulting to be  larger than the mean (or smaller).

It might help to specify, what I don't want:

- A uniform distribution would give specified values the same probability. For example, if I believe values between 0.1 and 0.2 are likely, each value is more or less equal to "happen".
- With a normal distribution the values smaller and larger than my mean would be equal likely with some sd.

**EDIT 2**

The undertaking: To predict, for example, the share of a given party in election 2, I start with the mean in election 1 (0.151). Additionally, I assume that the values in election 2 are more likely to be larger than 0.151, but of course, I can't be sure.

Comment: There's not enough information to begin to recommend one, outside the fact that you're describing something asymmetric. That's really not much of a basis to suggest something.

Comment: That is exactly my problem... Ideally I could just specify the mean and tell some function that it should be left or right skewed.

Comment: What do you expect this function to do with the information that it's skewed? It's not enough information - there's an infinity of right and left skew distributions.

Comment: Thanks for the additional information. I am not sure how you can have a mean of 15.1 if the mean is in [0,1]. What's the possible range of values taken by the data? It's not at all clear to me what you mean by "*the change I want to predict will be relatively small and start from the mean, resulting to be lbe larger than the mean (or smaller).*"

Comment: @Glen_b sorry for the artefact, it is 0.151, of course.

Comment: What's the possible range of values taken by the data (rather than the mean)? Are the data also "a share" and so also in [0,1]?

Comment: @Glen_b yes, the same holds for the data.

Comment: Are *exactly* 0 and *exactly* 1 possible with nonzero probability?

Comment: yes, but highly unlikely since the new mean will be in the vicinity of the old mean, only larger (or smaller).

Comment: I mean for the data rather than the mean. Can a proportion of the data be exactly 0 or exactly 1? (We're trying to identify a distribution for data, right?)

Comment: it is possible but unlikely, yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The possibility of values being exactly 0 and 1 would seem to rule out the just using the beta for all cases (otherwise I'd have suggested it earlier).

One possibility is to use a zero-one inflated beta - which can also be seen as a [mixture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixture_distribution#Finite_and_countable_mixtures) of a [beta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_distribution) and a [Bernoulli](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_distribution) - a distribution of the *mixed* type.

Conceived either way it will have four parameters; as a 0-1 inflated beta you'd have the probability at 0, the probability at 1 and the parameters of the beta that describes the remainder.

There's an infinity of other possibilities for skewed distributions in (0,1) of course, which could then be 0-1 inflated, but your specifications are vague and you'd probably want a distribution for which some software is available (see packages like `GAMLSS` and `zoib` in R for example, which will fit regressions where the response is of this type).

Answer (score 1):

[This gallery of distributions](http://itl.nist.gov/div898/handbook/eda/section3/eda366.htm) may be helpful.

Most common distributions are implemented in R, and you can use `??` to search, e.g., `??Cauchy`. If you are looking for the implementation of a *very* uncommon distribution in R and don't find it, you can search or ask at [SO in the R tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r).

Comment: Also check:    https://CRAN.R-project.org/view=Distributions

Answer (score 0):

Given the information that you have provided I suggest that you try the [Beta-distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_distribution). It has support in the interval [0,1] and is probably a good starting point. It is often used to model values that correspond to probabilities.

You should be able to fit the parameters of the distribution with this code:

```
library(MASS)
fitdistr(x,"beta",list(shape1=1,shape2=1))
```

Where `x` is the vector of your data.

Here I have randomly generated some data, fitted the distribution, plotted the data and the fitted model. I urge you to try this out, also it would be nice if you could contain an image similar to the one I post here! That could guide us in the right direction.

```
library(MASS)
x <- rbeta(10000,4,2)
hist(x,breaks=50, freq=FALSE)

# Estimate the parameters
vals <- fitdistr(x,"beta",list(shape1=1,shape2=1))  

# Plot the sampled data
hist(x,breaks=50, freq=FALSE)
# Generate the values to plot the curve
xx <- seq(0,1,len=100)
y <- dbeta(xx,vals$estimate[1],vals$estimate[2])
lines(xx,y,col='red',lwd=2)
```

Try to reproduce this plot with **your** data:

[image: Fitted beta distribution]

Comment: If I could specify, where the most dense region is (in your example about 0.78), from the mean, that would be perfect.

Comment: @Thomas you do not need to specify it, just make R "figure it out" Otherwise the mean is calculated as $\frac{\alpha}{\alpha+\beta}$, so in this case it would be $\frac{4}{4+2}=\frac{2}{3}$. $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are the shape parameters. The mode (*i.e. the peak around 0.78*) is calculated with $\frac{\alpha-1}{\alpha+\beta-2}$, in this case $\frac{3}{4}=0.75$.

Comment: Note that this information is all in the wikipedia link in the top of my answer.